# WPF DataTemplate Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I discovered when using a ContentTemplate/DataTemplate in a WPF TabControl my Bindings will not work anymore.

I have set up a small example to illustrate:

```
<Window x:Class="HAND.BindingExample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="BindingExample" Height="506" Width="656"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    >
<Grid>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="381"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="608">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=myString}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=myString}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Tab1 works as expected, Tab2 is empty.

the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace HAND
{
    public partial class BindingExample : Window
    {
        public string myString { get; set; }

        public BindingExample()
        {
            myString = "Hello Stackoverflow";

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `ContentTemplate` property incorrectly. From the [`ContentControl.ContentTemplate` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Gets or sets the data template used to display the content of the ContentControl.

Therefore, when setting this property, you also need to set the `Content` property to some sort of data source:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="TabItem">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=myString}"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="TabItem" Content="{Binding Path=myString}">
        <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Same conclusion as Miiite. Thank you very much also for the good explanation!

Comment: why do you need to set the Content="{Binding Path=mystring}" in the <TabItem> AND then also set Content="{Binding}" in the <Label>? In this example it doesn't seem necessary for the TabItem.ContentTemplate at all? Wouldn't it work just as well without the Template? I'm trying to understand templates and how I can bind other properties of the Label to parent's DataContext... thanks!

Comment: We data bind the `myString` property to the `Content` property to give it some value. Here, that value is just a single string, but it could have been an object with other properties. In the `ContentTemplate`, we tell it which part of the data bound object we want to display in the `Label`. In this case, we want to bind to the whole string object, so we use `{Binding}` to do that.

Comment: Noto though: the sample would work only for read-only bindings - if you changed `Label` to `TextBox`, myString would never get written back.

Answer (score 4):

```
<TabItem Content="{Binding myString}" Header="TabItem">
    <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
</TabItem>
```

But just so you know, to bind a window on itself, is just not the way to go.
I don't know if you did that just for the example, but if not try and create a proper viewModel to bind your window on ;)

Comment: I have it running on my machine. Maybe it does not run when you bind a window on itself, which I did not do.

Comment: Thank you! This works for my example. I am using a different binding class in my real world program using the MVVM pattern. I still do not understand why your code works and mine doesn't. I will now try to apply the solution of the example to my application.

Comment: Sheridan posted an answer with the same XAML code as mine, but with a better explanation of how the ContentTemplate works. It should help you understanding it

Comment: hi miiite, your answer worked for me, wrongly tested. make an edit to ur answer i will revert the downvote